# Как сделать три уровня кавычек в bash?

Tags: linux, postgresql, bash

Добрый день, коллеги!
Как отредактировать следующую строку для её корректного исполнения?

```
$ su postgres -c 'psql -c "alter role postgres with password 'postgres';"'
```

Проблема, собственно, в средних кавычках (password 'postgres')
Скрипт выполняется от имени root.

p.s. есть обходной вариант - пометить строку `psql -c "alter role postgres with password 'postgres';"` в ещё один sh-скрипт, и уже его выполнять через `su user -c`, но я не считаю это правильным.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
# su postgres -c 'psql -c "alter role postgres with password '"'"'postgres'"'"';"'
```

Comment: Логично, но нет... Пробовал. bash выпадает в ожидание ввода и ждет двойную кавычку.

Comment: @AlexandrBlinov обновил

Comment: Обновлённый подошел, спасибо! Я запутался в этих кавычках, прошу пояснить в чём смысл их такого количества и, главное, почему оно работает?

Answer (score 1):

Экранирование же ж в помощь:

```
su postgres -c "psql -c \"alter role postgres with password 'postgres';\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Один из `-c` можно исключить следующим образом:

```
$ sudo -u postgres -- psql -c "alter role postgres with password 'postgres';"
```

Answer (score 0):

В одинарных кавычках все символы. Используйте двойные кавычки в них можно экранировать одинарные и двойные.

```
su postgres -c "psql -c \"alter role postgres with password \'postgres\' ;\""
```

Answer (score 0):

для больших простыней я бы рекомендовал Встроенные документы `<< EOF`